# DropDownListFor returning a null list on post back

Tags: c#, asp.net, html.dropdownlistfor

When I post back my list in my DropDownListFor the selected item is set but the original list is set to null. If this is by design I can just repopulate the list but I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong. I don't have this problem with other html helpers.

Model

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Test.Models
{
    public class Test_Model
    {
        public List<SelectListItem> lstThing { get; set; }  
        public string strThing { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View

```
@using Test.Models

@model Test_Model

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.strThing, Model.lstThing)

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Test.Models;

namespace Test.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new Test_Model();
            model.lstThing = new List<SelectListItem>();
            model.lstThing.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "aaa", Value = "aaa" });
            model.lstThing.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "bbb", Value = "bbb" });
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Test_Model model)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Does the content of the list depend on the other values in the model or is the list static for the whole application?

Comment: It's static for the whole app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a new model instance on your post back.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(Test_Model model)
    {
       model.lstThing = new List<SelectListItem>();
       model.lstThing.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "aaa", Value = "aaa" });
       model.lstThing.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "bbb", Value = "bbb" });
       return View(model);
    }
```

You need to add back your SelectListItem items

Comment: I could've sworn the ListBoxFor saved the list on post back but I just tested it and I was wrong. Apparently It works the same as the DropDownListFor. Like you said, a new model instance gets posted back. That seems like a bad design but there must be some reason for that. Thanks!

Comment: it's because you are choosing to pass a new model back after the post. If you returned just the view, your dropdown should be populated.

Comment: @LinkListT No, that won't be the case. It also makes sense this way. The list itself is not part of the state of the model. It's nothing that the user is expected or should even be able to change. Plus, having to send back all that data would be a huge waste of resources.